# Maximal function of a complex Borel measure $\mu$ and the total variation $|\mu|$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm reading Rudin's *RCA* and I can't understand the following content.

> We shall study $D\mu$ by means of the *maximal function* $M\mu$. For $\mu\ge 0$, this is defined by
> $$(M\mu)(x)=\sup_{0<r<\infty}(Q_r\mu)(x),$$
> and the maximal function of a complex Borel measure $\mu$ is, by definition, that of its total variation $|\mu|$.

Here I'll explain the terminologies:

> The quotients $Q_r\mu$ is defined as follows:
> $$(Q_r\mu)(x)=\frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{m(B(x,r))},$$
> where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure and $B(x,r)$ denote the ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$.

> The symmetric derivative of $\mu$ at $x$ is defined as follows:
> $$(D\mu)(x)=\lim_{r\to0}(Q_r\mu)(x).$$

My question is, why the maximal function of a complex Borel measure is **by definition** the total variation $|\mu|$? Here Rudin only defined maximal functions for $\mu\ge 0$, and I cannot derive the fact from it. What's more, total variation is about Borel sets, i.e. it maps Borel sets to numbers, however, the maximal function is a function for numbers. I can't understand this. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The maximal function of a complex Borel measure $\mu$ is **not** the total variation $|\mu|$.

Comment: Then how do we understand the maximal function of a complex Borel measure?

Comment: It means that if $\mu$ is complex, then $M$ is the Maximal function of the total variation $|\mu|$.